# Counting t-shirt sizes in a column but also separated by commas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, sorting

I am counting sizes in a column but some of the cells also have extra sizes separated by a comma. The problem I am running into is counting "L" "XL" and "XXL".

The formula I am using to count "S" and "M" is this (it is an array function):

```
=SUM(LEN(B1:B17)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B17,"S","")))
```

This works for "S" and "M" but for large it counts 6 but I expect 5. This is due to XL in the list. This formula also doesn't work for "XL".

What I need help with is getting the formula to count each size correctly. "L" counts incorrectly and "XL" and "XXL" does not work.

Here is my list:

[image: My List]

Comment: When you have two values in the same cell separated by a comma, do you want to count each value (the same as if each value was in a separate cell)?  Are multiple values in a cell always the same?

Answer (score 0):

If

- `Cn` contains the size to count
- `Sizes` is the range being examined

  - `Sizes refers to:   =Sheet2!$B$1:$B$17`
- Multiple sizes in the same cell are separated by commas

---

```
D1: =SUMPRODUCT(--(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(Sizes&",",",",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99,198},99))=C1))
```

If you might have more than three sizes in the same cell, change the array constant to reflect that.

- The formula creates an array of values consisting of the different sizes, or, if there are multiple sizes within a cell, puts them into two different elements of the array.

  - *There will be some elements in the array that are all spaces, to account for the cells that have only a single size mentioned*
- Then we just need to see if an array element is equal to the size we want to count.
- Sumproduct adds that up.

---

Use the formula evaluation tool for a better idea of how this works.

[image]